# How to receive broadcast message from Hub class in SignalR client using C#?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a scenario where one of the clients is sending a request to Hub Class method `AddMessage`, which in turn should broadcast that message to all clients including the one who initiated it.

The problem is that I am able to call the Hub method `AddMessage` from the client as shown in the following code, but I couldn't find a way to handle the broadcast message on the client side which is initiated in the Hub class using the following line.

```
Clients.All.NotifyMessageToClients(name, message);
```

*SignalR Hub Class*

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class SignalRChatHub : Hub
{
    public void AddMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        // Following call is supposed to notify all clients with passed parameters. 
        // They could have a method called NotifyMessageToClients to fetch the broadcasted message

        Clients.All.NotifyMessageToClients(name, message); 
    }
}
```

*SignalR Client*

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    HubConnection hubConnection;
    IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy;

    public Default()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:6898/");
        stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("SignalRChatHub");
    }

    async public void SendAddNotification(string msgFrom, string msg)
    {
        // Following line calls Addmessage method in SignalRChatHub class
        await stockTickerHubProxy.Invoke("Addmessage", "Ajendra", "Hello StackOverflow");
    }

    // I might need the method NotifyMessageToClients here... to receive broadcasted message
}
```

I have some idea about how to achieve the same in jQuery but not in C# by creating a client as I did above. How would I achieve this?

If the above approach doesn't make sense in any way, please suggest me the right one.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the way you have written this question, it is not really clear what you are asking here. Are you asking how to broadcast a message to all clients? Because you already did that. Or are you asking how to receive them on the clients end? Or perhaps you don't know how to set up a connection from the clients side? In any way, please try to be as explicit as possible in your questioning, and maybe you can tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Dennis1679 sorry for the confusion, please check the Edit section for more clarity. Hope it's clear now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to listen to events from the server like this:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    HubConnection hubConnection;
    IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy;

    public Default()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:6898/");
        stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("SignalRChatHub");

        // listen to server events...
        // n is "name" and m is "message", but you can change to "a" and "b" or anything else...
        stockTickerHubProxy.On<string, string>("NotifyMessageToClients", (n, m) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message received from server. Name: {0} | Message: {1}", n, m);
        });

    }

    // "async" methods should return Task instead of void....
    // unless they are event handlers for UI applications...
    public async Task SendAddNotification(string msgFrom, string msg)
    {
        // first, start the connection...
        await stockTickerHubProxy.Start();
        // Following line calls Addmessage method in SignalRChatHub class
        await stockTickerHubProxy.Invoke("Addmessage", "Ajendra", "Hello StackOverflow");

        // you don't stop the connection, otherwise you won't be able to receive calls from the server
    }

}
```

...if you need to update UI in WPF, for example, you should implement your event like this:

```
stockTickerHubProxy.On<string, string>("NotifyMessageToClients", (a,b) => 
    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            // update UI...
            textBox.Text += string.Format("Name: {0} | Message: {1}", a, b);
        })
);
```

---

I suggest reading [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#wpfsl) for deeper details.

Comment: thanks for the answer. You have mentioned about updating UI in WPF, is there any way to update the UI on the client side who are using web application. I'll mark it as an answer soon :)

Comment: @AjendraPrasad you're welcome. In web applications the client code should be javascript in order to update the DOM. if you implement a client in the server side, it won't be able to update UI, as far as I know.

Comment: thanks for the point. I am now able to do so by following the link, where absolute URL is a reference in javascript to point to the server.

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/how-to-push-data-from-server-to-client-using-signalr.htm

Comment: @halfer oh, thank you so much for sharing it, I've just fixed it. Actually I should update it soon, as I'm learning Spark + Kafka + Cassandra.

Comment: @Alisson: ah, that sounds good. Too little time, too many toys! Docker was my last one, Laravel is the current one, React next. Phew...

Comment: @halfer React sounds interesting. Docker is my next one, actually it's the next thing I'm trying to implement in our release pipeline (we are automatically building and deploying through VSTS). Good luck with Laravel and React!!!

Comment: Thanks! You can have a play with Docker and CI completely free of charge. I'm using CircleCI for the build machines since they have a free tier of 1500 build minutes/month. GitLab is also worth looking at for build pipelines (2000 minutes). I use GitLab for the Docker registry (10G per project, also free).